# The difference between struct::type+using and just using?

Tags: c++, c++14

I saw a lot of code on the similarity:

```
namespace _private {
    template <class T>
    struct identity
    {
        using type = T;
    };
}
template <class T>
using identity = typename _private::identity<T>::type;
```

What is the difference between a simple:

```
template<class T>
using identity = T;
```

Other sample:

```
template <typename A>
struct Int4 : std::integral_constant<int, 4> {};
```

vs

```
template <typename A>
using Int4 = std::integral_constant<int, 4>;
```

Comment: In the `Int4` case there is a difference, the first makes a new type, that can overload-resolve separately, while the second just makes an alias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The`::type` identity blocks template type deduction.  The raw using does not.

The `struct` Int4 is a distinct type from integral constant 4; it simply has the constant as a public parent type.  the using is not a distinct type.

Both of these differences can have broad knock-on effects that are far too extensive to cover in a SO answer.

Comment: "The::type identity blocks template type deduction". Do you mean this feature? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: @TadeuszKopec No.  `template<class T> void foo( identity<T> t )` will not deduce `T` if `identity` is the first definition above.  There are other somewhat similar situations where it is blocked for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is effectively "read a C++ textbook", however, I feel there is a more nuanced answer that's useful when using C++ libraries.

`typedef` and `using` do not declare new types, but are merely aliases for existing types. This can lead to very subtle, but annoying errors if you are using a large library and wish to forward declare a definition but the definition itself is typedef-ed.

**Large Include**

```
struct my_s {};
using my_struct = my_s;
// ...
```

**Source**

```
//#include "large_include.h"
struct my_struct;
#include "large_include.h"    // compiler error, no issue if we do `struct my_s;`
```

Even though you may see what these names hold as very similar entities at your current level of C++ understanding, the compiler treats them very differently. Aliases and new types can both be great: know their differences.

Also, adding new types are clearly different.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
struct a {};
struct b: a {};
struct c: a {};
using d = c;

int main()
{
     std::cout << std::is_same<b, c>::value << std::endl; // false
     std::cout << std::is_same<c, d>::value << std::endl; // true
}
```